# Google Api Parsing in json

Tags: android, ajax, json

How can I parse this URL in JSON format?

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=&rsz=8"

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private Context context;
    private static String url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=pixelloid&rsz=8";

    private static final String TAG_VTYPE = "responseData";
    private static final String TAG_VCOLOR = "results";
    private static final String TAG_FUEL = "GsearchResultClass";
    private static final String TAG_TREAD = "url";
    private static final String TAG_OPERATOR = "url";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_POINTS = "experiencePoints";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
    }

    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        private ListActivity activity;

        // private List<Message> messages;
        public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

        /** application context. */
        private Context context;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_VTYPE, TAG_VCOLOR,
                            TAG_FUEL, TAG_TREAD }, new int[] {
                            R.id.vehicleType, R.id.vehicleColor, R.id.fuel,
                            R.id.treadType });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            // selecting single ListView item
             lv = getListView();






        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            if (json == null) {
                   // notify user
                Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");

            } 
             else {
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String vtype = c.getString(TAG_VTYPE);

                    String vcolor = c.getString(TAG_VCOLOR);
                    String vfuel = c.getString(TAG_FUEL);
                    String vtread = c.getString(TAG_TREAD);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_VTYPE, vtype);
                    map.put(TAG_VCOLOR, vcolor);
                    map.put(TAG_FUEL, vfuel);
                    map.put(TAG_TREAD, vtread);
                    jsonlist.add(map);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("==>", "iyogbr;g;ui");

                }
            }
             }

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

I'm parsing this data:

```
{"responseData":{"results":[{"content":"<b>Pixelloid<\/b> Studios Visual Effects, 3D Animation Production and Training Institute.","GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","titleNoFormatting":"Pixelloid - Visual Effects, 3D Animation - Production and Training","title":"<b>Pixelloid<\/b> - Visual Effects, 3D Animation - Production and Training","cacheUrl":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/search?q=cache:Uq3_USWdbwIJ:www.pixelloid.com","unescapedUrl":"http:\/\/www.pixelloid.com\/","url":"http:\/\/www.pixelloid.com\/","visibleUrl":"www.pixelloid.com"},{"content":"Pixelloid Studios Visual Effects, 3D   Animation Production and Training <b>...<\/b>","GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","titleNoFormatting":"Production and Training Institute - Pixelloid","title":"Production and Training Institute - <b>Pixelloid<\/b>","cacheUrl":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/search?q=cache:Pce2UIgSVDoJ:www.pixelloid.com","unescapedUrl":"http:\/\/www.pixelloid.com\/training\/","url":"http:\/\/www.pixelloid.com\/training\/","visibleUrl":"www.pixelloid.com"},{"content":"<b>Pixelloid<\/b> is an award winning 3D Animation &amp; Visual Effects Production and   Training Studio based in Hyderabad with branches in Bangalore, Visakhapatnam   <b>...<\/b>","GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","titleNoFormatting":"Pixelloid Studios - YouTube","title":"<b>Pixelloid<\/b> Studios - YouTube","cacheUrl":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/search?q=cache:wrfWBrpn45AJ:www.youtube.com","unescapedUrl":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/user\/pixelloid","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/user\/pixelloid","visibleUrl":"www.youtube.com"},{"content":"<b>Pixelloid<\/b>, Hyderabad, India. 5896 likes · 60 talking about this · 408 were here. We   help people tell their stories effectively. We do animation, visual effects for <b>...<\/b>","GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","titleNoFormatting":"Pixelloid - Hyderabad, India - Media\/News\/Publishing | Facebook","title":"<b>Pixelloid<\/b> - Hyderabad, India - Media\/News\/Publishing | Facebook","cacheUrl":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/search?q=cache:_m-PNJ9c3sgJ:www.facebook.com","unescapedUrl":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/Pixelloid","url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/Pixelloid","visibleUrl":"www.facebook.com"},{"content":"Welcome to the company profile of <b>Pixelloid<\/b> Studios Private Limited on LinkedIn.   <b>Pixelloid<\/b> is an award winning Content Creation Company with an active <b>...<\/b>","GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","titleNoFormatting":"Pixelloid Studios Private Limited | LinkedIn","title":"<b>Pixelloid<\/b> Studios Private Limited | LinkedIn","cacheUrl":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/search?q=cache:vnyg3sUrGfgJ:www.linkedin.com","unescapedUrl":"http:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/company\/pixelloid-studios-private-limited","url":"http:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/company\/pixelloid-studios-private-limited","visibleUrl":"www.linkedin.com"},{"content":"The latest from <b>Pixelloid<\/b> (@<b>Pixelloid<\/b>). <b>Pixelloid<\/b> is an award winning 3D   Animation &amp; Visual Effects studio with a dedicated commercial training division.","GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","titleNoFormatting":"Pixelloid (Pixelloid) on Twitter","title":"<b>Pixelloid<\/b> (<b>Pixelloid<\/b>) on Twitter","cacheUrl":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/search?q=cache:s4gJgJcovCsJ:twitter.com","unescapedUrl":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/Pixelloid","url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/Pixelloid","visibleUrl":"twitter.com"},{"content":"Feb 10, 2013 <b>...<\/b> <b>Pixelloid<\/b>, Hyderabad is the only training institute in India that has an active   production environment. <b>Pixelloid&#39;s<\/b> courses are tailored to the <b>...<\/b>","GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","titleNoFormatting":"Pixelloid - Admission, Courses, Fee, Address | Pixelloid | Hyderabad ...","title":"<b>Pixelloid<\/b> - Admission, Courses, Fee, Address | <b>Pixelloid<\/b> | Hyderabad <b>...<\/b>","cacheUrl":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/search?q=cache:3OWFak05f30J:www.minglebox.com","unescapedUrl":"http:\/\/www.minglebox.com\/college\/pixelloid-Hyderabad","url":"http:\/\/www.mi
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [rules](http://stackoverflow.com/about) of this website, and maybe re-submit your question. You have to give us more to work with.

Comment: i have tried it but its resulting null response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the way json serializes objects. Basically (very basically) `{...}` are objects, `[...,...]` are arrays and `key:value` are object properties, so something like:

```
{
  "responseData": {
     "results": [],
     "cursor": {
         "moreResultsUrl": "http://www.url.com",
         "searchResultTime": "0,00"
     }
  },
  "responseDetails": null,
  "responseStatus": 200
}
```

Means that you have a first object that has 3 properties: `responseData`(object), `responseDetails`(null object) and `responseStatus`(int). And `responseData` is an object with 2 properties: `results` (array) and `cursor`(object). And `cursor`'s properties are `moreResultsUrl`(string), and `searchResultTime`(string).

and now, for parsing the json you can try something like this:

- Take in mind that your code provided was too cloned-from-tutorial. You will have to edit things a little bit more in order to maintain some grade of parameter naming (your variables talk about cars and your data about web searches...). And you may rename some data from `ListAdapter adapter = new Simple...` method in order to fit your needs.

** In order to use these JSON methods, you need to include the simple json library.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity { 

private Context context; 
private static String url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=pixelloid&rsz=8";

private static final String TAG_content = "content";
private static final String TAG_GsearchResultClass = "GsearchResultClass";
private static final String TAG_titleNoFormatting = "titleNoFormatting";
private static final String TAG_title = "title";
private static final String TAG_cacheUrl = "cacheUrl";
private static final String TAG_unescapedUrl = "unescapedUrl";
private static final String TAG_url = "url";
private static final String TAG_visibleUrl = "visibleUrl";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
}

private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    private ListActivity activity;

    // private List<Message> messages;
    public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

    /** application context. */
    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( context, contents, R.layout.list_item, 
                                    new String[] { TAG_title, TAG_content, TAG_url }, 
                                    new int[] { R.id.vehicleType, R.id.vehicleColor, R.id.fuel, R.id.treadType });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        //lv = getListView();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
            loadJson();
            return null;
    }
}

public static JSONObject parse() {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj = parser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        json=(JSONObject)obj;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}

private String moreResultsUrl = "";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contents;

public void loadJson() {

    try {
        JSONObject obj = parse();
        if(obj!=null) {
             JSONObject responseData;
             responseData = (JSONObject ) obj.get("responseData");

             if(responseData !=null) {
                JSONArray results =  (JSONArray) obj.get("results"); 
                contents = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                HashMap<String, String> map;
                JSONObject cro;
                for(int i=0;i<results.length();i++) {
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    cro = (JSONObject) results.get(i);

                    map.put(TAG_content, cro.get(TAG_content).toString() );
                    map.put(TAG_GsearchResultClass, cro.get(TAG_GsearchResultClass).toString() );
                    map.put(TAG_titleNoFormatting, cro.get(TAG_titleNoFormatting).toString() );
                    map.put(TAG_titleNoFormatting, cro.get(TAG_titleNoFormatting).toString() );
                    map.put(TAG_title, cro.get(TAG_title).toString() );
                    map.put(TAG_cacheUrl, cro.get(TAG_cacheUrl).toString() );
                    map.put(TAG_unescapedUrl, cro.get(TAG_unescapedUrl).toString() );
                    map.put(TAG_url, cro.get(TAG_url).toString() );
                    map.put(TAG_visibleUrl, cro.get(TAG_visibleUrl).toString() );

                    contents.add(map);
                }

                JSONObject cursor =  (JSONObject ) responseData.get("cursor");
                if(cursor!=null)  moreResultsUrl = cursor.get("moreResultsUrl").toString();
             }
         }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can u provide me detailed code if possible,iam very  beginner

Comment: You have to gather the json parts in order. You are starting with a iteration, and the global wrapper is an object. Read again my response, including the explanation of the json. In the code provided I'm strarting exactly how you must do it (the parsing stuff). You just need to continue it