# How to put in an intent an ArrayList<JSONObject>

Tags: android

I want to transfer from one Activity to another an ArrayList through the intent. How can I do that, since I can't make the JSONObject class to implement `parcelable`

Comment: Why can't it be Parcelable?

Comment: Well JSONObject class isn't a class I created it is derived from org.json.JSONObject how can I make it implement parcable?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082122/passing-jsonobject-into-another-activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply put an entire JSONObject as a string.

```
intent.putString("YOUR_KEY", jsonObj.toString);
```

And then in the SecondActivity you can convert the Json String into JsonObject

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY"));
```

**You can Create a ArrayList i.e json.ToString()**

```
JSONObject json1 = null,json2 = null;
ArrayList<String> jsonList=new ArrayList<String>();
jsonList.add(json1.toString());
jsonList.add(json2.toString());
i.putStringArrayListExtra("json_list", jsonList);
```

And then in the SecondActivity you can convert the Json String into JsonObject

```
JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("json_list").get(0));
JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("json_list").get(1));
```

Answer (score -1):

To change from one `Activity` to another, you need an intent. And you can put extra info to this intent. Not all types are available, but String is*:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.extras.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

*You can find more info at: [Passing a Bundle on startActivity()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity)

As you may know, you can transform an `ArrayList` to a `JSONArray` and this last one can be serialized as a string**:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("foo");
list.add("baar");
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);
```

**You can find more info at: [convert ArrayList<MyCustomClass> to JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841952/convert-arraylistmycustomclass-to-jsonarray)

Now you only need to put your array-string  to your intent and parse it again on your recently opened class***:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
```

***More info at the first link

Comment: Ok but then how can I transform my String into ArrayList<JSONObject> ?

Comment: should be something like new JSONArray(value).
Then you have a JSONArray and from there you can then get the objects inside

Comment: @libathos, on the last step, you have an string that has a JSONArray of JSONObjects json-encoded. You just need to parse the json string and "re-mount" your ArrayList... It's a simple JSON routine. Check my answer on this link where a user doesn't know how to parse a JSON to put it in a ListView, the parsing part is similar to what you need to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179610/google-api-parsing-in-json/19180887#19180887

Comment: mBundle.extras - wrong
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle); - Where is the key?